# Failed Homebrew Installation

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I was trying to re-install homebrew on my Mac. I used the following command.

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

I got the following error. Could someone help me with what to do here?

```
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
error: RPC failed; HTTP 403 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 403
fatal: expected flush after ref listing
Failed during: /usr/bin/git fetch --force origin
```

Comment: That means that Github is declining your request for some reason. Are you on a shared internet connection of some sort?

Comment: I'm connecting to Internet from my `personal hotspot`.

Comment: I used `non-VPN` network, yet getting the same `error`

Comment: Similar issue on GitHub https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4014

Answer (score 0):

Taking your device to a couple networks would be prudent to be sure it's an issue on your macOS and not just transient network communication issues.

This is the command to test:

```
curl -I https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh
```

I get the following lines at the end of the output of the command below (and `echo $?` shows a zero exit status for the curl to get details on the install script)

> expires: Thu, 30 Nov 2023 17:23:20 GMT
> source-age: 0
> content-length: 30633

---

Other installation methods are documented:

- https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

the git mirror section or the untar section would get around blocks of the main git hub communications path that the default install needs to run.